# Callback isn't called

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I use the following code and it seems that the callback (Which start with `Im HERE`) is not called, any idea why?

```
console.log("im starting");
process.start(function() {
  //this line doesnt called
  console.log("im HERE");
  server.listen(app.get('port'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(' listen to: ' + app.get('port'));
    }

  });
});
```

the method start are called and finish ...any idea what it can be ?

before ive added the `process.start` the code look like following:
And this works **OK**, now I need to add this `process.start` and when it **finish** to do the `server.listen`

```
module.exports = (function() {
  server.listen(app.get('port'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('listen ' + app.get('port'));
    }
  });
}());
```

**UPDATE**

This is the code of process start

```
exports.start = function () {

    Validator.validateJson(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

    plugin.parse().then(function (conf) {
        require.cache.pe.configObj = conf;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    envHandler.eventE.on('AppP', function () {
        console.log('User port ' + require.cache.per);
    });
    var run= function () {
        return Promise.all([
            childPro.create(path.join(value)),
            childPro.findAndUpdateUser()
        ]).spread(function (cmd,updatedAppEnv) {
            return Promise.all([childProc.executeChildProcess('exec', cmd, updatedAppEnv), Promise.delay(50).then(function (results) {
                return inter.ProcessRun(val);
            })]);
        })
    }();

}
```

**I use promise lib like bluebird if its matter in this case**

Comment: What is `process.start`? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @MinusFour - this is my internalAPI ...this is not related to node internal API...

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to give that code to us, as clearly that's where the problem is.

Comment: so the callback of `process.start` is not called? you should probably post that function then..

Comment: If `process.start` is calling the callback, then `start` method is more relevant that the callback itself...

Comment: @cviejo - process.start was called but the server listen code doesnt called...

Comment: Also, there's really absolutely nothing wrong in that bit of code that you've posted, so we can only make blind guesses. You should post the code surrounding that bit too...

Comment: @cviejo - console.log("im HERE"); is doesnt called

Comment: Ok, then the problem is within `process.start`. Add it

Comment: @cviejo - sure in 2 min

Comment: How do you know it was called if the `console.log` isn't run and the server listen code isn't run?!

Comment: @DaveNewton - please see my update

Comment: @KevinB - please see my update

Comment: @cviejo - please see my update

Comment: That's exports.start(), what about process.start()?

Comment: @shopiaT your start method doesn't accept a callback...

Comment: @LucasRodriguez - this is the code the file is called process...

Comment: @KevinB - so what should I do in this case? can you please advice ?

Comment: @LucasRodriguez the file code process.js and the start is the method which I run on it...

Comment: You should add a `callback` parameter in the `start` function definition and call it once you're done...

Comment: @shopiaT make it accept a callback, and execute the callback when you want it to continue...

Comment: @KevinB - can you please provide example as answer with my context Im a bit confusing  :(

Comment: @cviejo can you please provide example with my context ? Thanks!!!!

Comment: `function (foo) { foo(); }`

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks but this is not helping :(

Comment: @cviejo - can you please assist ?

Comment: Well, @shopiaT, the problem is also, where do you want to call that callback? There's a lot of conditions there

Comment: @cviejo - I need it to call at the end of the start after the run function was called but not sure how to combine it with the server code...

Comment: do you need to wait for the `run` function to be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102515/discussion-between-cviejo-and-shopia-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear where you want to call the callback. In short, change the start function to accept a `callback` parameter and call `callback()` when you are done (or pass it at end as argument to `then`).

```
exports.start = function (callback) {

    Validator.validateJson(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

    plugin.parse().then(function (configObj) {
        if (typeof require.cache.persist === 'undefined') {
            require.cache.persist = {};
        }
        require.cache.persist.configObj = configObj;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    envHandler.eventEmitterIns.on('AppPortDef', function () {
        console.log('User port ' + require.cache.persist.port);
    });
    var run= function () {
        return Promise.all([
            childPro.create(path.join(value)),
            childPro.findAndUpdateUser()
        ]).spread(function (cmd,updatedAppEnv) {
            return Promise.all([childProc.executeChildProcess('exec', cmd, updatedAppEnv), Promise.delay(50).then(function (results) {
                return inter.ProcessRun(val);
            })]);
        })
    }();

    run.then(callback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 1+ can you please just add the server code how should I call to this start ?

Comment: Same as you did before

Comment: but I shouldn't add additional parameter ? are you sure?

Comment: Edited, put the callback after `run` is done. What additional parameter do you mean? Continue in the chat above, if  you have any questions